# Quasar many vue errors "chunk chunk-common [mini-css-extract-plugin]"

Tags: vue.js, webpack, server-side-rendering, quasar-framework, quasar

I have configured the quasar to SSR mode and got many errors of css-extract. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRxFp.png)

***Here's what I've attempted:***

- Utilized import/sort-order in ESLint and sorted the imports alphabetically.
- Added an ignore-order for my Quasar webpack config.
- Explored potential solutions from GitHub webpack issues.
  However, when running my project in SSR mode, I observed a peculiar behavior. During the initial render, the project lacks styles. Styles only become visible when the user clicks on another link and the styles correctly connecting.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Expect the correct styles of project.
In project I use vue3 and in components use scss language in styles module.
My quasar config:

```
/* eslint-env node */

/*
 * This file runs in a Node context (it's NOT transpiled by Babel), so use only
 * the ES6 features that are supported by your Node version. https://node.green/
 */

// Configuration for your app
// https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/quasar-config-js

/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */

const { configure } = require('quasar/wrappers')

function parseEnvVariables(envs) {
  const keys = Object.keys(envs).filter((e) => e.startsWith('VUE_APP'))
  let result = {}
  keys.forEach((k) => (result[k] = envs[k]))
  return result
}
module.exports = configure(function (ctx) {
  return {
    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/supporting-ts
    supportTS: {
      tsCheckerConfig: {
        eslint: {
          enabled: true,
          files: './src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx,vue}',
        },
      },
    },

    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/prefetch-feature
    preFetch: true,

    // app boot file (/src/boot)
    // --> boot files are part of "main.js"
    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/boot-files
    boot: ['axios', 'vue-recaptcha-v3', ['vue3-notion/nuxt', { css: true }]],

    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/quasar-config-js#Property%3A-css
    css: ['app.scss', '~vue3-notion/dist/style.css'],

    // https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/tree/dev/extras
    extras: [
      // 'ionicons-v4',
      // 'mdi-v5',
      // 'fontawesome-v6',
      // 'eva-icons',
      // 'themify',
      // 'line-awesome',
      // 'roboto-font-latin-ext', // this or either 'roboto-font', NEVER both!

      'roboto-font', // optional, you are not bound to it
      'material-icons', // optional, you are not bound to it
    ],

    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/quasar-config-js#Property%3A-build
    build: {
      env: require('dotenv').config().parsed || parseEnvVariables(process.env),
      vueRouterMode: 'history', // available values: 'hash', 'history'
      webpackManifest: true,

      //   transpile: false,
      //   publicPath: '/',

      // Add dependencies for transpiling with Babel (Array of string/regex)
      // (from node_modules, which are by default not transpiled).
      // Applies only if "transpile" is set to true.
      // transpileDependencies: [],

      // rtl: true, // https://quasar.dev/options/rtl-support
      preloadChunks: true,
      // showProgress: false,
      gzip: true,
      // analyze: true,

      // Options below are automatically set depending on the env, set them if you want to override
      // extractCSS: false,

      // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-webpack
      // "chain" is a webpack-chain object https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain
      // chainWebpack (/* chain */) {}
    },

    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/quasar-config-js#Property%3A-devServer
    devServer: {
      server: {
        type: 'http',
      },
      port: 8080,
      open: true, // opens browser window automatically
    },

    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/quasar-config-js#Property%3A-framework
    framework: {
      config: {},

      // iconSet: 'material-icons', // Quasar icon set
      // lang: 'en-US', // Quasar language pack

      // For special cases outside of where the auto-import strategy can have an impact
      // (like functional components as one of the examples),
      // you can manually specify Quasar components/directives to be available everywhere:
      //
      // components: [],
      // directives: [],

      // Quasar plugins
      plugins: ['Notify'],
    },

    // animations: 'all', // --- includes all animations
    // https://quasar.dev/options/animations
    animations: [],

    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/developing-ssr/configuring-ssr
    ssr: {
      pwa: false,

      // manualStoreHydration: true,
      // manualPostHydrationTrigger: true,

      prodPort: 3000, // The default port that the production server should use
      // (gets superseded if process.env.PORT is specified at runtime)

      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
      // Tell browser when a file from the server should expire from cache (in ms)

      // chainWebpackWebserver (/* chain */) {},

      middlewares: [
        ctx.prod ? 'compression' : '',
        'render', // keep this as last one
      ],
    },

    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/developing-pwa/configuring-pwa
    pwa: {
      workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW', // 'GenerateSW' or 'InjectManifest'
      workboxOptions: {}, // only for GenerateSW

      // for the custom service worker ONLY (/src-pwa/custom-service-worker.[js|ts])
      // if using workbox in InjectManifest mode
      // chainWebpackCustomSW (/* chain */) {},

      manifest: {
        name: '',
        short_name: '',
        description: '',
        display: 'standalone',
        orientation: 'portrait',
        background_color: '#ffffff',
        theme_color: '#027be3',
        icons: [
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-128x128.png',
            sizes: '128x128',
            type: 'image/png',
          },
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-192x192.png',
            sizes: '192x192',
            type: 'image/png',
          },
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-256x256.png',
            sizes: '256x256',
            type: 'image/png',
          },
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-384x384.png',
            sizes: '384x384',
            type: 'image/png',
          },
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-512x512.png',
            sizes: '512x512',
            type: 'image/png',
          },
        ],
      },
    },

    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/developing-cordova-apps/configuring-cordova
    cordova: {
      // noIosLegacyBuildFlag: true, // uncomment only if you know what you are doing
    },

    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/developing-capacitor-apps/configuring-capacitor
    capacitor: {
      hideSplashscreen: true,
    },

    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/developing-electron-apps/configuring-electron
    electron: {
      bundler: 'packager', // 'packager' or 'builder'

      packager: {
        // https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#options
        // OS X / Mac App Store
        // appBundleId: '',
        // appCategoryType: '',
        // osxSign: '',
        // protocol: 'myapp://path',
        // Windows only
        // win32metadata: { ... }
      },

      builder: {
        // https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration

        appId: 'apiId',
      },

      // "chain" is a webpack-chain object https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain
      chainWebpackMain(/* chain */) {
        // do something with the Electron main process Webpack cfg
        // extendWebpackMain also available besides this chainWebpackMain
      },

      // "chain" is a webpack-chain object https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain
      chainWebpackPreload(/* chain */) {
        // do something with the Electron main process Webpack cfg
        // extendWebpackPreload also available besides this chainWebpackPreload
      },
    },
  }
})
```